# How to setup proxy in Anypoint Studio - Mulesoft

Tags: proxy, mule

Hi Guys Im working throught a POC using the endpoint below which is also used in some of the online sample tutorial

```
http://tshirt-service.cloudhub.io/?wsdl
```

In my solution i have a "Web Service Consumer" which is pointing to the above WSDL. Everything loads fine - all operations are listed in the configuration (when connected to my office network).

When i try to deploy this solution (while still connected to the office network), the build script is failing at the point where it tries to retrieving the document for the above WSDL as shown in the below image

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT0ii.jpg)

When i run this solution at home all is OK. The build is able to retrieve the WSDL from the above endpoint without any issues. From this it seem as if the proxy in my Anypoint needs setting. So i had a look at the preferences in Anypoint and all seem to be OK as shown in the image below. Can someone please help me as im not sure whats going on here. If my proxy is set why is it not working on my office network?

[image of proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K91v4.jpg)

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: No i didnt get an answer for this